# AngularJS 1.2 and IE9 strange behaviour with page title

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

In my Angular application I have one static page title:

```
<title>Title</title>
```

A problem appears when I'm changing the view with `$location.path('/home')`. IE appends the string `$/home` to my page title, like this:

> Title#/home#/home

After a while, the title string becomes so long that IE displays an error and I have to refresh page. When I change the view by clicking `<a href='#/home'>` links, the page title isn't changed.

How can I prevent this when using `$location.path()`?

Comment: Do you have any plunker or fiddler for this?

Comment: Which exact version of AngularJS 1.2.x ? Did you check reported issues with some over pushstate matters?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it in Plunker and it work perfectly. Here it is:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pObS5qM0gd2Cr5iKnk8f

Notice that `$location.path('/home')` could be called without "/".

`$location.path('home')`

Comment: This might work be an answer. But try to add that code over here. Do not give an external site reference unless needed.